# erro no ionic serve

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

PS C:\ionic\appmysql> ionic serve

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
> [ng] An unhandled exception occurred: ngcc is already running at process with id 12260.
> [ng] If you are running multiple builds in parallel then you might try pre-processing your node_modules via the command line ngcc tool before starting the builds.
> cli/ngcc/**ngcc_lock_file**.)
> [ng] See "C:\Users\AlvgMaker\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Imd7P3\angular-errors.log" for further details.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).

```
    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

PS C:\ionic\appmysql> npm i
npm WARN @ionic-native/native-storage@5.31.1 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

87 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
PS C:\ionic\appmysql> ionic serve

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
> [ng] An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@ionic-native/native-storage" has missing dependencies:
> [ng]  - @ionic-native/core
> [ng] See "C:\Users\AlvgMaker\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-u1RWk0\angular-errors.log" for further details.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).

```
    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Comment: please edit your question with not only copy-pasted code but also human-friendly text which explains your issue. Formulating your question also helps you to frame the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the package:

> @ionic-native/core

use the follow code:

> npm i @ionic-native/core

more in: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/core